# git show only tagger and date for tag

Tags: git, tags

I wish to extract tagger name and e-mail from git tag from usual git repo. If I say `git show -q <mytag>`. git shows me something like this:

```
tag <mytag>
Tagger: tagger <mail>
Date:   tagdate
Tagcomment
commit hash
Author: commitauthor <mail>
Date: commitdate
Commit comment
```

For my scripting purposes I need only tagger with his mail and tag date. I tried a lot, but unable to find any way to ask git to print only this info. I do not want to use `grep` or other shell tools and do not want git to print full commit. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(tagger)' refs/tags/$(TAG)
```

That will extract the tagger name, tagger email, and tag date.

If you need more fine grain control you can use `taggername`, `taggerdate`, etc.